# Google Chrome - Auto Detect Location

Tags: google-chrome

I am working from India, for a UK Client. I don't want Google Chrome to Auto Detect my Current Location. I need to edit manually to change the prefer location I need. As of now Chrome says, I am in UK and if I manually change the location, its asking me to enter the valid Zip Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about disable your location sharing in Google Chrome

Go to [Location Sharing](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142065)

Answer (score 2):

1. Click the wrench icon  on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Settings.
3. Click the Under the Hood tab.
4. Click Content settings.
5. In the page that appears, scroll down to the "**Location**" section. Select your default permission for future location requests:

**Allow all sites to track my physical location:** Select this option to let all sites automatically access your location.

**Ask me when a site tries to track my physical location:** Select this option if you want Google Chrome to alert you whenever a site requests your location.

**Do not allow any site to track my physical location:** Select this option to automatically deny site requests for your location.

Click **Manage exceptions** to remove previously-granted permissions for specific sites.

Answer (score 0):

Is it actually some site detecting your current location, not JavaScript locally? If so, it is done using your IP address. The only way out is to use an anonymous "elite" proxy (which hides the client's IP and does not report it in any of the HTTP headers.) More on [anonymizers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymizer).